# Skip keys in array without values in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

I have a normal one dimensional array, let's call it **$myarray**, with several keys ranging from [0] to [34]. Some keys could be empty though.

Suppose I want to use such array in a foreach loop

```
 $i = 1;
 $choices = array(array('text' => ' ', 'value' => ' '));
 foreach ( $myarray as $item ) :
      $count = $i++; 
      $choices[] = array('text' => $count, 'value' => $count, 'price' => $item);
 endforeach;
```

I'd wish to skip in this foreach loop all the empty keys, therefore the other array I'm building here (**$choices**) could have a smaller amount of rows than **$myarray**. At the same time, though, as you see, I count the loops because I need an increasing number as value of one of the keys of the new array being built. The count should be progressive (1..2..3..4...).

thanks

Comment: Do you mean if one of the values is empty? Keys/indices cannot be empty in an array.

Comment: yes in that sense, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) will remove empty elements from an array

You can also use `continue` within a loop to skip the rest of the loop structure and move to the next item:

```
$array = array('foo', '', 'bar');

foreach($array as $value) {
  if (empty($value)) {
    continue;
  }

  echo $value . PHP_EOL;
}

// foo
// bar
```