# preg_match pcre regexp

Tags: php, preg-match

i have a litte problem with wrote correct reg exp, i have a string

`2013-01-11 17:38:02.137759 some text leater`

or

`11 Jan 17:38:02 some text leater`

so i wrote a reg exp

```
(?:(?:(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?)\s(?:[^\s]+)\s(?:.\d+.)?\s?))?((?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:(\w{3}\s+\d+)\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))
```

the example result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jan 11 17:38:02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jan 11 17:38:02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jan 11
        )

)
```

or

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-11 17:38:02.137759
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-11 17:38:02.137759
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

the problem is the result i wanna skip a empty field result's how can i do that?

Thanks for help

Comment: start debugging: split that regex into multiple separate ones, and test each chunk individually. when they work, THEN you can start trying to combine them into `opt1|opt2|opt3` and keep debugging at that level.

Comment: What part do you want to extract from the string? Your current regex seems overly complicated.

Comment: So you basically want to remove empty values: [first Google result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347296/skip-keys-in-array-without-values-in-a-foreach-loop).

Comment: yes thanks, but i need to do that only using regular exp

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would just be to use `array_filter` on the result:

```
array_filter($array, function ($piece) { return array_filter($piece); });
```

Comment: thanks, its good but i need to do that only using regular expression